# Save data in multiple rows using foreach cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, foreach

I am working in cakephp to save multiple data using for each.
i have save data in session it is working fine.
but i'm troubling with the offest in foreach loop.
Here is Controller to save multiple data:

```
 foreach($currentSessionData as $key):
                   // debug($key);
                    $this->request->data[$table_name]['tutor_name'] = $key['tutor_name'];
                    $this->request->data[$table_name]['area_id'] = $key['area_id'];

                    $this->$table_name->save($this->request->data);
                    endforeach;
```

when i debug $currentSessionData i get array like:

```
array(
'application_attachment' => '',
'desc' => '',
'Post' => array(
    'tutor_name' => 'Muhammad Usman',
    'tutor_email' => 'usman@gmail.com',
    'tutor_number' => '123123',
    'tutor_gender' => 'male',
    'city_id' => '2',
    'tutor_address' => 'asdasdas',
    'area_id' => array(
        (int) 0 => '3',
        (int) 1 => '4'
    ),
    'user_id' => '47'
)
```

)
debug($key) return:

```
array(
'tutor_name' => 'Muhammad Usman',
'tutor_email' => 'usman@gmail.com',
'tutor_number' => '123123',
'tutor_gender' => 'male',
'city_id' => '2',
'tutor_address' => 'asdasdas',
'area_id' => array(
    (int) 0 => '3',
    (int) 1 => '4'
),
'user_id' => '47'
```

)
when i write

```
 $this->request->data[$table_name]['tutor_name'] = $key['tutor_name'];
 $this->request->data[$table_name]['area_id'] = $key['area_id'];
```

it gives an error of illegal string offset.

if i simply save $key like:

```
 foreach($currentSessionData as $key):
                    $this->$table_name->save($key);
                    endforeach;

                $this->Session->setFlash('Account created!');
```

it gives error:
 Array to string conversion [CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php, line 1009]

And also why foreach does not iterate '0' index.
Any Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you not accepting any answers of your questions?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($currentSessionData as $k=>$v):
        if ($k === 'Post') {
            $this->request->data[$table_name]['tutor_name'] = $v['tutor_name'];

            for($i=0;$i<count($v['area_id']);$i++){

                $this->request->data[$table_name]['area_id'] = $v['area_id'][$i];
                $this->$table_name->save($this->request->data);
            }

        }

    endforeach;
```

But again in area_id you have another array, you need to decide which value you need to keep. Also read more about arrays.

Comment: lie ... i need to save all values in area_id in next row.

Comment: so for this, 'area_id' => array((int) 0 => '3',(int) 1 => '4') the actual area_id is 34?

Comment: Also in your solution in if condition you are using $k.
if ($v === 'Post')

Comment: your solution is also giving error ..
string to array conversion.

Comment: that's because you need to decide which value you keep from area_id....do you keep all values from area id? How do you add them together? Cause right now you have two values in the area_id and only one area_id column in your database i'm guessing.......

Comment: yes. I think you miss understand the question.
question is i want to save all values in area_id field in rows with same tutor_name.

Comment: so for each area_id value that a user has you want to save an entry? Like for your example you want to save one entry with tutor name = Muhammad Usman + area_id = 3 and another entry with tutor name = Muhammad Usman + area_id = 4?

Comment: yes.. this is what i want to save.
can you help with that ?

Comment: sorry brother.. i've already used nested loop .. this does not save whole array .. it only save fist index for area_id.
it is just saving .. muhammad usman + 3  and not muhammad Usman + 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
foreach($currentSessionData as $key):             
    $this->request->data[$table_name]['tutor_name'] = $key['Post']['tutor_name'];
    $this->request->data[$table_name]['area_id'] = $key['Post']['area_id'][$i]; //$i= 0 or 1 ( only or your given array)
    $this->$table_name->save($this->request->data);
endforeach;
```